# Jquery form submit doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to submit a simple form but the result of the #createVMForm log (shown in the code below) is empty.

But I can see the values in the browser url bar ...

```
<form id="createVMForm" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" value= "hi" required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">User Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageName">Image Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="imageName" id="imageName" required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="memory">DC Memory (in MB):</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="memory" id="memory" required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="vcpu">Number of VCPUs:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="vcpu" id="vcpu" required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="vncUsername">VNC Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vncUsername" id="vncUsername" required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="vncPwd">VNC password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="vncPwd" id="vncPwd" required="true">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create DC</button>
</form>

$('#createVMForm').submit(function() {
    console.log($('#createVMForm').serializeArray());
});
```

Comment: Well, your event handler is not preventing the submit, so the page will submit regardless of what you do in that handler.  Is this all of your code though?  Cause the snippet you have just has loose javascript thrown in with html without a script tag.

Comment: $('#createVMForm').serialize() should work. Maybe try giving your form an action, even if its just "#/".  Also make sure your javascript is actually in a <script>...</script> block.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting the whole page by default

Change this:

```
    $('#createVMForm').submit(function() {
         console.log($('#createVMForm').serializeArray());
     });
```

To this:

```
    $('#createVMForm').submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log($('#createVMForm').serializeArray());
     });
```

This will stop the form from submitting the page and allow you to do things inside of the jQuery block.